# UIPrintInteractionController, turn off Double-sided option?

Tags: ios, printing, uiprintinteractioncntrler

When using UIPrintInteractionController,

it is easy to turn off the 'page range' and 'number of copies' options

```
UIPrintInteractionController *pic =
      [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.delegate = self;
pic.printInfo = pif;
pic.printFormatter = formatter;
pic.showsPageRange = NO;
pic.showsNumberOfCopies = NO;
```

[image]

Is there a way to TURN OFF the **Double-sided** option?

Conversely, has anyone actually confirmed with Apple, that it is impossible to turn off the double sided option?  If so thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problem. It is really silly that the duplex option in UIPrintInteractionController doesn't work.

Comment: tyhanks @quemeful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

var duplex: [UIPrintInfoDuplex](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPrintInfo/duplex)

As per official documentation:-

> If a printer is capable of duplex printing, a switch in the printing
>   options allows users to toggle between single-side and double-sided
>   printing. See the description of the [UIPrintInfoDuplex](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIPrintInfoDuplex) constants for
>   more information.

```
enum UIPrintInfoDuplex : Int {
    case None
    case LongEdge
    case ShortEdge
}
```

none: No double-sided (duplex) printing; single-sided printing only.

```
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
printController.printInfo = printInfo//printController is instance of UIPrintInteractionController
```